# Implement photoshop blending mode in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, photoshop, blending

There were numerous situations when designers gave me psd files, and there two layers where set with blending mode multiply. and always I couldn't implement that behaviour, and just used different colour for front view with opacity set to, for instance, 0.5, just to some kind of simulate this blending mode behaviour. However now I just want to implement what designer has given me. 
For instance, let us take a UITableView. Here is the screenshot of custom design.

[image: Custom UITableView]

Here the section header isn't half opaque, but it has blending mode set to Multiply. And here is the actual colour of it

[image: Actual section header color]

If I set custom view as a section header, with background colour set to above screenshot, how can I make the section view "blend" with the background of the UITableView???

This was just an example of the problem that I've stumbled multiple times. In general, I always have a front view and a rare view, and in photoshop front view is set, for instance, multiply blend mode with rare view, and I want to have the same effect with iOS. Is there any way to implement this??

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS image processing script from Pixastic: http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/blend/

I used this script before for several projects, it works realy great :)

Hope it helps you)

Comment: This is iOS not javascript.

Comment: Sorry, I can be wrong but I thought that JS as well can be used by iOS development. If not I think that the Multiply effect barely can be achieved.